# Unsupported ONNX opset version: 17

Tags: pytorch, yolo

I want to export a yolo model to the ONNX format:

```
python export.py --weights yolov5s.pt --include onnx
```

But I am having this output:

```
export: data=data/coco128.yaml, weights=['yolov5s.pt'], imgsz=[640, 640], batch_size=1, device=cpu, half=False, inplace=False, keras=False, optimize=False, int8=False, dynamic=False, simplify=False, opset=17, verbose=False, workspace=4, nms=False, agnostic_nms=False, topk_per_class=100, topk_all=100, iou_thres=0.45, conf_thres=0.25, include=['onnx']
YOLOv5  v7.0-185-g2334aa7 Python-3.9.16 torch-1.12.0+cu102 CPU

Fusing layers... 
[W NNPACK.cpp:51] Could not initialize NNPACK! Reason: Unsupported hardware.
YOLOv5s summary: 213 layers, 7225885 parameters, 0 gradients

PyTorch: starting from yolov5s.pt with output shape (1, 25200, 85) (14.1 MB)

ONNX: starting export with onnx 1.12.0...
ONNX: export failure ❌ 0.1s: Unsupported ONNX opset version: 17
```

I have searched for answers about this issue but could not find one.

I am using Ubuntu 20.

Thanks!

Comment: "Unsupported hardware"! Your GPU is too old